# Why does my while loop not return any values?

Tags: python

I’m new to computer science and just got my first assignment but I’m unsure how to proceed as my while loops do not return anything. Please help. The idea is to find how many small pies it would take to make up a larger one (where the area was previously calculated and set to pie1/pie2) and then print the result. The code looks like this:

```
    def quantity_of_pies(pie1, pie2)
       num_of_pies = 0
       if pie1 > pie2:
            while pie1 % pie2 != 0:
                 pie1 = pie1 + pie2
                 num_of_pies += 1
        elif pie2 > pie1:
             while pie2 % pie1 != 0:
                 pie2 = pie1 + pie2
                 num_of_pies += 1
         return num_of_pies
```

Comment: What inputs are you providing when calling your function?

Comment: `pie1 % pie2 != 0` is an odd choice. `6 % 2` is equal to 0, but that would end your while loop prematurely.  Perhaps instead `while pie1 != pie2` would make more sense. Or if these aren't whole numbers, then `while pie1 < pie2:` would break once pie1 gets too big. Furthermore, `if pie1 > pie2` then why would you do `pie1 = pie1 + pie2`, growing the larger pie over and over again? I feel like if you sprinkled some print statements around to see what values are being produced at each of your logic would be illuminating.

Comment: At any rate, can you share sample inputs and expected output. I think it would help understand more about how this is supposed to work (sharing the question from your homework might help too). My naive approach would just be `return pie1 / pie2 if pie1 > pie2 else pie2 / pie1` but I'm guessing the question/requirement is more complicated.

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop at all. It's just a matter of division and rounding the answer up to the nearest integer.

Comment: You should correct the unusual and inconsistent indentation in your code.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use division (or multiplication)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an infinite loop, since:

```
a % b == (a + b) % b
```

The number of small pies in the big one could simply be

```
max([pie1,pie2])/min([pie1,pie2])
```